# Specify server address to client program

Tags: java, tcp, connection

I'm starting to learn about TCP connection and using Sockets/ServerSockets in java. Right now I'm specifying the server address in the program. How are you supposed to define the server address? If the application is rolled out and the IP address changes it doesn't work.

Comment: Generally, the address is something that should be externally configurable or "well-known" to both the server and client.

Comment: But how do you make it well known?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind your server socket to an unspecified host address, the socket will be bind to all available interfaces (see [InetSocketAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#InetSocketAddress-int-)).

```
// Usually loaded from external configuration.
String host = "";
int port = 12345;
ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
if (host != null && !host.isEmpty(""))
    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
else {
    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
}
```

Another way to achieve that would be to allow external configuration of the host. For example, using a [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file, or command line arguments.

Comment: All true but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP his question is "How are you supposed to define the server address?". My solution allows him to bind the socket on all interfaces, which pretty much fill this requirement: there is no need to define an IP when you can automatically bind to the available interfaces. I've mention properties & command line arguments as well, in case this solution is not good enough.